# Grouping by day from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have 2 tables: "orders" and "visits". in the orders table i'm saving some details about the order including "userIP" and "orderDate". in the visits table i'm saving details everytime a user visiting my web page including "userIP" and "visitDate". i'm using ASP.NET and SQL SERVER 2005. 
i want to create a statistic table whitin i save the number of users visited and the number of users that ordered **BOTH GROUPED BY DAY** so far i got:

```
  select count(userIP) as NumOfOrders,
         dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, orderDate),0) as Date
    from Orders
group by dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, orderDate), 0)
```

this works fine and give me the number of orders grouped by day,
but how do i add the total visits grouped by day to this?

Comment: How do your Orders and Visits table link to each other?

Comment: @Raj More - this shoud be link like this: orders.userIP = visits.userIP AND orders.dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, orderDate),0) = visits.dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, visitDate),0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
SELECT v.userIP, NumOfVisits, NumOfOrders, v.Date
FROM (
    SELECT userIP, count(*) as NumOfVisits,
         dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, visitDate),0) as Date
    FROM visits
    GROUP BY userIP, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, orderDate), 0)) v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT userIp, count(*) as NumOfOrders,
         dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, orderDate),0) as Date
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY UserIP, dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, orderDate), 0)) o
 ON o.UserIP = v.UserIP
    AND o.Date = v.Date
```

and your result should be like:

```
78.34.5.11 | 3 | 1 | 2009.10.06
78.34.5.19 | 9 | 0 | 2009.10.06
```

if you don't need to group by userIP, you can do this:

```
SELECT NumOfVisits, NumOfOrders, v.Date
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) as NumOfVisits,
         dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, visitDate),0) as Date
    FROM visits
    GROUP BY dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, visitDate), 0)) v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) as NumOfOrders,
         dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, orderDate),0) as Date
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, orderDate), 0)) o
 ON o.Date = v.Date
```

and your result will look like:

```
12 | 1 | 2009.10.06
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(O1.Date, V1.Date) Date,
       COALESCE(O1.NumOfOrders, 0) NumOfOrders,
       COALESCE(V1.TotalVisits, 0) TotalVisits
FROM 
     (select dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd, 0, O.orderDate)) Date,
             count(O.userIP) NumOfOrders
        from Orders O
    group by dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd, 0, O.orderDate))) O1
FULL JOIN
     (select dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd, 0, V.visitDate)) Date,
             count(V.userIP) TotalVisits
        from Visits V
    group by dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd, 0, V.visitDate))) V1
on O1.Date = V1.Date
```

Comment: @najmeddine - O.orderDate = V.visitDate this won't work. You need to join using Date only (without time).

Comment: this solution is giving me a cartesian product which does'nt make sense.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't focused. Now fixed.